# Is there a more efficient way of setting up rules from large lists?

Tags: replacement

I wrote a code for converting a string into a Morse code.

```
convert[text_String] := 
  StringJoin[
    Map[
      Replace[
        {"a" -> ".- ", "b" -> "-... ", "c" -> "-.-. ", 
         "d" -> "-.. ", "e" -> ". ", "f" -> "..-. ", "g" -> "--. ", 
         "h" -> ".... ", "i" -> ".. ", "j" -> ".--- ", "k" -> "-.- ", 
         "l" -> ".-.. ", "m" -> "-- ", "n" -> "-. ", "o" -> "--- ", 
         "p" -> ".--. ", "q" -> "--.- ", "r" -> ".-. ", "s" -> "... ", 
         "t" -> "- ", "u" -> "..- ", "v" -> "...- ", "w" -> ".-- ", 
         "x" -> "-..- ", "y" -> "-.-- ", "z" -> "--.. ", " " -> "/ "}], 
      Characters[text]]]
```

Example

```
convert["a ladybug loves sleeping"]
```

gives

> `.- / .-.. .- -.. -.-- -... ..- --. / .-.. --- ...- . ... / ... .-.. . . .--. .. -. --.`

I'm getting the correct output. However, when I coded my list of rules, I typed in every rule ("a"->".- ", "b"->"-... ", etc.) individually. I am wondering, how could I produce a set of rules in a more efficient way. Say I had a thousand of rules to create from two existing lists, making a list of rules from the two list by hand would be too tedious.

Comment: `Thread[list1->list2]`?

Comment: I believe your question is something like: "If I had a really large alphabet how could I automate this list creating process?" Well, if I understood you correctly, the morse code is a convention, so no easy way for that. But if you accept using binary instead of morse things get interesting.

Comment: Incidentally this should be written using `StringReplace` as it will be much faster, i.e. `convert[text_String] := StringReplace[text, { (* rules *) }]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
Given that you already have your lists

```
morseAlphabet = {"·−","−···","−·−·","−··","·","··−·","−−·","····","··","·−−−","−·−","·−··","−−","−·","−−−","·−−·","−−·−","·−·","···","−","··−","···−","·−−","−··−","−·−−","−−··"}
```

and

```
alphabet = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

You can use

```
Thread[alphabet -> morseAlphabet]
```

to create your replacement rules.

```
StringJoin[Characters["A LADYBUG LOVES SLEEPING"] /.Thread[alphabet -> morseAlphabet]]
```

Would then be equivalent to your function `convert[text_String]`

Comment: Yes, that was the function I was looking for! Thanks!